# indexOf can find null

Tags: java, arraylist, null

This is my implementation of the indexOf method (custom arraylist class)

```
public int indexOf(String string) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(strings[i].equalsIgnoreCase(string)){
            return i;
        }   
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is the code that should return null, but which doesn't. I don't understand why

```
public void indexOf_can_find_null() {
     StringArrayList lst = list("1", "2", null, "3", "4", "3", "2", "1");
     assertEquals(2, lst.indexOf(null));
}
```

Comment: Post code for `list()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will never work. You cannot use the `equalsIgnoreCase()` to test for `null`.

The `equalsIgnoreCase()` method does a comparison on the the VALUES of the strings.  A null string has no value.  When you use `null` you are saying that this String object does not reference anything, hence it has no value, therefore nothing with a value can ever be equal to it.  If you had a null object BEFORE calling `equalsIgnoreCase()`, then a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown, so it doesn't work in either direction.

If you used the `==` operator it would allow you to test the reference of the string, which `null` would work out, however this cannot be used for string comparison.  If you really wanted this to work you'd need to combine the methods:

```
if(strings[i] != null && strings[i].equalsIgnoreCase(string))
    return i;
else if(strings[i] == null && string == null)
    return i;
```

Comment: In fact the code is valid Java, just missing stuff. I made the same mistake :/

Comment: I guess that depends on how we're defining valid.  OP's code block would not compile without a **bunch** of other stuff.

Comment: Valid code means it conforms to Java syntax. And it is only missing list() method and StringArrayList class.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `NullPointerException`. When i=2, `strings[i]` is `null`, then `strings[i].equalsIgnoreCase(string)` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

PS: without the code of `list()`, this is just a wild guess

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when i = 2, you'll have:

```
string[2].equalsIgnoreCase(string) evaluates to null.equalsIgnoreCase(string)
```

This will throw a null pointer exception as a null reference is used.